# How can I make this method statically acessable?

Tags: java, static

I have a method in a class TaskPane extending JPanel:

```
void updateGui(TaskList tl) { 
    removeAll();
    for (int x = 0; x <= tl.getTaskCount(); x++){
        add(new JCheckBox(tl.getTask(x).getName()));
    }
    setVisible(true);
}
```

The non static methods such as removeAll(); 
cannot be called from static method so what should i do 
to be able to acess this method from other classes like 
TaskPane.updateGui();

Comment: Answers have been posted. But for further help, post the full TaskPane class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am right then the `updateGui` method is `void static updateGui`. Now , if you make updateGui method as `static` then it is owned by the class . i.e all objects will share the same copy of `updateGui` method . Such methods are created if it is not an object specific behavior but rather an utility method . So in my opinion you should change your method as follows:

```
public static void updateGui(TaskPane tp, TaskList tl) { 
    tp.removeAll();
    for (int x = 0; x <= tl.getTaskCount(); x++){
        tp.add(new JCheckBox(tl.getTask(x).getName()));
    }
    tp.setVisible(true); 
}
```

And you can call this method in following way:

```
TaskPane.updateGui(object of TeskPane, object of TaskList);
```

Or, If you are calling this method specifically within your `TaskPane` class then it can be called as:

```
updateGui(this,object of TaskList);
```

Comment: Thanks i'm trying this method atm

Answer (score 0):

You can't make this method available from a static context. What you need to do is find a way to push an instance of your class to the `TaskPane.test()` method.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to fill a bottle or drive a car, you need to have the bottle to fill or the car to drive.

It's the same with Java objects. To be able to call a method of an object, you need a reference to the object. So, in one way or another, the `TaskPane.test()` method needs to have a reference to the `TaskPane` to update. With the code you posted, it's hard to give you a more concrete answer. Maybe it's the responsibility of `TaskPane.test()` to create a new TaskPane instance, or maybe it should receive a TaskPane instance as argument.